# Does anyone know which language supported by the Kindle SDK?

Tags: kindle, kindle-kdk

I just wanna know which language supported by the Kindle Development Kit. I mean, does UTF-8 full supported by this SDK (`Specially RTL languages`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Java, full UTF-8 support.

[developers website](http://kdk.amazon.com/gp/public/gateway)

Answer (score 1):

Through random clicking I found the, or, possibly, one of several, API's:

https://kdk-javadocs.s3.amazonaws.com/2.0/index.html

The main site:

http://kdk.amazon.com/

is not available:

[image: not available]